# Facebook sdk and Bolts framework (duplicate symbols)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, xcode7

I added Parse 1.10 with Bolts ,when I build an error FacebookSDK.h not found occurs , If I add FacebookSDK framework this occurs.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._URL in

87 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
```

If I remove facebookSDK one of Parse header file says FacebookSDK.h not found

and

If I remove Bolts framework one of Parse header file says Bolts.h not found

I downloaded latest FacebookSDK but It does not have FacebookSDK.framework , It contains FBSDKLogin,FBSDKMessengerShareKit and so on...
So I used FacebookSDK.Framework from an old project.

I'm Stuck , Plz Help.

Thanks

Comment: There should be a framework called FacebookCoreSDK.framework. That's required for use of all other facebook's sdk

Comment: I also recommend you to use cocoapods. It takes care of all the errors you're facing now

Comment: @Wassim There is no FacebookCoreSDK.framework in updated FacebookSDK and How do I install cocoapods ?

Comment: That's something really weird because i always use it in my projects. Look it up in facebook developers page

Comment: I included FBSDKCorekit.framework but no use.

Comment: Did u add it to your embedded & linked libraries

Comment: Mate, i guess it's time for you to learn cocoapods & let it handle all this confusion. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook v4.8 SDK does not have facebooksdk.framework.
If you are using the latest version of Parse then,i would recommend using the latest version of facebook sdk too.
Follow this links for making sure that you are integrating it properly.

> [Facebook getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)
>
> [Parse FB integration](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook)

For basic login and graph api request from Facebook and linking it to Parse.You need to include FBSDKCoreKit.framework,FBSDKLoginKit.framework,FBSDKShareKit.framework,Parse.framework
I hope that,it helps!